# Specify multiple possible patterns for a single command

Tags: linux, unix, sed, text-editor

Basically there a few lines which contain a common format, but different wording at the end. The command will work for all of them, but I want to match all possible pattern, thereby needing only 1 line in the script. As an example, I know how to make the script work like so:

```
/pattern1/ s/asdf/ghjk/g
/pattern2/ s/asdf/ghjk/g
/pattern3/ s/asdf/ghjk/g
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your patterns are really as similar as in your example, you can use

```
sed -e '/pattern[1-3]/ s/asdf/ghjk/g'
```

If the patterns aren't so similar and your `sed` command supports extended regular expressions, you can use

```
sed -E -e '/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)/ s/asdf/ghjk/g'
#   ^^ use extended regular expressions
#      for GNU sed, use -r or escape (, |, and ) with \
```

If your `sed` command doesn't support extended regular expressions, you might have to turn to `awk` or `perl`:

```
perl -ple '/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)/ && s/asdf/ghjk/g'
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to do this without the -E switch?

Comment: If you're using GNU `sed`, you don't need the `-E` option if you escape the extended regular expression special characters with backslashes: `gnused -e '/\(pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3\)/ s/asdf/ghjk/g'`